# Regular expression to extract the last part without domain

Tags: python, regex

Good afternoon,

I would like to know how to extract the last part of the path from URL as string, but without domain using Regex from Python style.

The url is: 'https://ncd.soft.com/lags/**prime-amazon**.png' (prime-amazon is my objective)

I tried with no exit because we need to exclude the domain (.png or .com, etc)

```
([^/]+(?!.png))/?$
```

Bad result

```
prime-amazon.png
```

I expect:

```
prime-amazon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[^/]+(?=\.png/?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GpYy2h/1).

*Details*:

- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `(?=\.png/?$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `.png` or `.png/` till end of string immediately to the right of the current location.